# Is it possible to pass className to React-Bootstrap Tab?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a tabbed navigation in a React app implemented using React-Bootstrap `Tabs` and `Tab` components. I can pass a custom `className` to `Tabs`, but if I try to do the same with the `Tab` component, it isn't added to its list of classes.

I haven't been able to find examples that do pass `className` to `Tab`, and there's no mention of this in the official documentation (though to be fair, being able to pass `className` to `Tabs` is also not really documented, except for in the examples).

Is it really not possible to pass a custom `className` to `Tab`? Any idea why this is not supported? Or, is there another way of doing that?

Comment: You have to pass `tabClassName` prop to Tab in order to apply a custom class on `<Tab>` component. You can take a look [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tabs/#tabs-props)

Comment: @SyedUzairBukhari I did try `tabClassName`, still doesn't work.

Comment: It should work that's the official prop for passing a custom class to Tab component.